# How to center child div when both the parent and child elements have different % widths

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, centering

I have two rows with three div on each row. How do I center the three div within each row when the rows have widths of 100% and each div has a width of 28%? I'm also trying to get the div to stay centered and be responsive to different devices (like phones, tablets, desktops, and laptops).

I've tried:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
```

and:

```
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Phones*/

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.insideRows {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.buttons {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border: solid 3px #3366ff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


/*For Tablets*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-m-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
}


/*For Desktops/Laptops*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-3 {
    width: 28%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="insideRows">
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="insideRows">
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flexbox for `.insideRows`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.insideRows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*Phones*/

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.insideRows {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.buttons {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border: solid 3px #3366ff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


/*For Tablets*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-m-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
}


/*For Desktops/Laptops*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-3 {
    width: 28%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="insideRows">
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 1 Column 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="insideRows">
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-m-5 buttons">Row 2 Column 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```